# is DroidText any good?

Tags: java, android, itext

There's a lot of info out there about its LGPL license and the legal stuff, but is it *actually* any good?

`iText 2.1.7` has (to quote the sales guy at iText) a `"few technical and also legal problems"`.

I know he's a sales guy and he probably wanted to put me off so that I'd buy a commercial license (and I definitely don't blame him for doing so, don't get me wrong), but can anyone actually give me an example of a popular, well-rated app out there that uses DroidText?

Is DroidText, actually any good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough cred to leave comments.  This might not be what you are looking for, but I work for a (non-profit) firm that is developing a tablet application that will be used by law enforcement.  We are using DroidText to convert onscreen forms and activities to a pdf.  While it isn't going to be an app for public use, the reaction from the police has been very positive so far.

So yes, DroidText is "good"